# Checking if a state is an eigenstate of $L^2$ and $L_z$ without performing calculations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, linear-algebra, spherical-harmonics

If I have a given state $\psi$ which is a linear combination of [spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics), and I am asked if its an [eigenstate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_state#Pure_states) of $L^2$ and $L_z$, is there a way to do it without using the [eigenvalue equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Overview)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, $Y_{\ell m}$ is an eigenvector of $L^2$ with eigenvalue $\ell(\ell+1)\hbar^2$, and an eigenvector of $L_z$ with eigenvalue $m\hbar $. If you have a linear combination $\psi = \sum_i c_i Y_{\ell_i m_i}$, then
$$L^2 \psi = \sum_i \big[\ell_i(\ell_i+1)\hbar\big]c_i Y_{\ell_i m_i}$$
$$L_z \psi = \sum_i \big[m_i\hbar\big] c_i Y_{\ell_i m_i}$$

If you want $\psi$ to be an eigenvector of $L^2$ or $L_z$, then you need to be able to pull the eigenvalues out front of the summation. Can you see what that would  mean for the possible values of $\ell_i$ and $m_i$ which appear in your sum?

Comment: This means that i would only need to check the values of $l$ and $m$. If all the values of $l$ are equal to each other then $\psi$ is an eigenvector of $L^2$. Likewise, if all $m$ are equal to each other then $\psi$ is an eigenfunction of $L$. Thank you very much.